# vuejs jsx with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jsx

I am able to use typescript with single file component(.vue files) but when i try to use it with (.jsx files) it does’nt work and gives me two errors, one in my index.ts file, I'm not sure if i have done anything stupid in my configuration files,

**'vue' module not found**

and second error when building a solution as attached screenshot

[image: build webpack error]

tsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./built/",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "noEmitOnError": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "module": "es2015",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "jsxFactory": "h",
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
      ]
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*",
      "test/**/*"
    ],
    "files": [
      "jsx.d.ts"
     ]
  }
```

Comment: Why would you use jsx? The beauty of Vue is that you can include real html in your SFC files.

Comment: @Kokodoko Sometimes it is necessary to write the render function directly (with or without JSX) instead of a template. With render functions you get full control.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript compiles `.tsx` file as per React. `Vue JSX` compiles differently than React JSX. `Vue + JSX + TypeScript` is not yet supported. This issue is currently tracked on GitHub.

See more for this issue:
[GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13260)